# Docker run copies to filesystem?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand how Docker manages the filesystem. When start a new container, does it create a new "filesystem" and copy files into it and when I stop/kill it, does it clean it up?

Are there any links that describe how Docker manages files?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, when you fire up a docker container, the filesystem of the docker image is available to the container in a read only mode.  A writable, and initially empty, filesystem "layer" is put on the top and all changes made by the executing process(s) in the container write to that top layer.  Any file from the lower layers touched by the executing container is copied up to the top writeable layer and modified there.  All such copied up files hide the lower layer copies of the file.

Note, if you were to create another image from the state of the container after it's ran for a while, the delta's that have accumulated in the top writeable layer would become part of that new images read-only base filesystem in any containers created from that new image.

This link gives an overview.

http://docs.docker.com/terms/layer/

Comment: Thanks for the link. In browsing the docker site, I also came across this useful link: http://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/